# Getting source code with of a NuGet package in VS

Tags: c#, github, nuget

Is there a way to link a source code of an open sourced C# library? For example, I would like to be able to see the implementation of a certain function but it is not provided when I simply add the package using NuGet.

Comment: Probably not, but depends on author of nuget package. Did something similar for some internal nuget packages. Required symbol indexing, and bundling the .pdbs along with the binaries. Then when you'd step into the package code VS would use the symbol indexing in the pdb to pull the code from version control, and continue stepping through. Without the symbol indexing, ILSpy would help.

Comment: Might be easier to use a VS decompilation extension. Resharper (not free) has pretty good tooling for this. There are almost certainly alternatives to resharper that are free. Obviously if you're decompiling, the resulting code is rarely a line-for-line match of the original source, but the logic and flow will be exactly the same.

Comment: _"open sourced c# library"_ - I would _assume_ there is a project site with the source code (repository) as an alternative to a Nuget package (re: clone/fork etc). Otherwise, probably not. As mentioned you can probably decompile with some tool, though that source code would likely be "unreadable" (re: think "minified", renamed variables etc)